# More entries in GRUB2

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit on an external HDD (Samsung M3 Portable, 500GB) and want to add other entries for various diagnostic software (UBCD, bitdefender antivirus...) to GRUB on the same disk.

Is it possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

You may use `grml-rescueboot` for ISO Boot

A very simple way of creating a GRUB menuentry for a bootable ISO file is to use grml-rescueboot.

- The package does the following:

  1. Creates a /boot/grml folder.
  2. Automatically adds menuentries to the GRUB menu for any ISO files located in the /boot/grml folder. This is accomplished whenever the update-grub command is executed.
  3. The created menuentry, when selected, provides submenu options on how to boot the ISO, including the "Try Ubuntu" and "Install" options.
- To use the grml-rescueboot option:

  1. Install grml-rescueboot

     ```
     sudo apt-get install grml-rescueboot
     ```
  2. Place bootable ISO files in the /boot/grml folder.

     Since this is a system folder, the operation must be conducted as "root". For example, if the ISO is located in the user's Downloads folder, the command would be:

     ```
     sudo cp ~/Downloads/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso /boot/grml/u1404_64_d.iso
     sudo chmod +rx /boot/grml/u1404_64_d.iso
     ```
  3. Update GRUB

     ```
     sudo update-grub
     ```

Tested on: Ubuntu 14.04 64bit
Source:  [Grub2/ISOBoot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot)

---

Another way, using `memdisk` from `syslinux-common` package:

1. If `memdisk` is not in `/boot/`, copy it from `/usr/lib/syslinux/memdisk`
2. Copy ISO image to `/boot/`

   ```
   sudo cp ~/Downloads/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso /boot/u1404_64_d.iso
   sudo chmod +rx /boot/u1404_64_d.iso
   ```
3. Edit `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` or create new custom file and append to it:

   ```
   menuentry 'ISO rescue disk' {
           linux16   /boot/memdisk iso bigraw
           initrd16  /boot/u1404_64_d.iso
   }
   ```
4. Update GRUB

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```

Tested on: Ubuntu 14.04 64bit, **Didn't work for me** Unable to find CDROM!
Reference: [Syslinux/MEMDISK](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/MEMDISK)

Comment: Well, I tried both and nor of these are working. MEMDISK error: no ramdisk image specified. The first solution just restarts GRUB

Comment: @RadoslavFatura, I've tested memdisk before with floppy img with grub2 and iso with pxe. Let me check iso with grub2 on my local machine then back to you.

Comment: I was thinking... Is it possible to make new partition with those isos on syslinux bootloader and chainload it somehow?

Comment: @RadoslavFatura, Yes, it seems possible (as USB key). I tried this morning chainloading from Grub2 to syslinux but no success yet.

Comment: Hmmm, so the only thing we have is the iso load in bootloader. But it's not working so I assume it must be something in iso then (mean Ultimate Boot CD). Since syslinux isn't working what about grub4dos?

Comment: @RadoslavFatura The error `MEMDISK error: no ramdisk image specified` means the `initrd16` command failed and the ISO image was not loaded. Most likely this is because the ISO image is too large. Apparently Grub can't load **initrd** images larger than 462 MB, this limit is related to the Linux boot process. In that case Grub also prints the error message `error: couldn't find suitable memory target`. More details [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1055686) and [here](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-grub/2015-02/msg00007.html).

Comment: @gregn3, Thank you for the info. I don't have that setup right now. That limit of `initrd` could be only with grub but with grub2 it should be higher the 1st setup can load 1.2GB disk image. I really want to know, I will recreate this set in vbox or another machine, create new question here and let you know. At least take some rep :) to thank you and it could help other users.

Answer (score 0):

I made Hirens Boot CD in 2. partiton, chainlinked it and it's working :D

Via Grub Customizer I made new entry (type chainloader) and pointed to partition where is Hirens Boot CD extracted.

Thank you anyway :D